# Node Js as server http to consume external web service

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap

I want to install Node Js to consume a external web service in SOAP. 
This is the architecture:

`|Webshere application| ---HTTP---> |Node Js| ----HTTPS--> ||External Web Service||`

This is the script I am doing:

```
var http = require('http');
var httpntlm = require('httpntlm');
var options  = {
   url: "https://serverexterno/WebServiceSOAP?wsdl"

}

const server = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
let body = '';
let headers = req.headers
let as400Response ='';

req.setEncoding('ascii');

req.on('data', (chunk) => {
body += chunk;
 });

httpntlm.post(options,       
        function (err, resp) {
            console.log (resp);
            if(err) {

                 return console.log(err);

            }
                console.log( resp.headers);
                console.log("resp.body" + resp.body);

                body = resp.body;

               res.statusCode = 200;
               return res.end(resp.body);
        });

        console.log ('Finish ....');
} catch (er) {




res.statusCode = 400;
  return res.end(`error: ${er.message}`);
    }
  });


});

server.listen(8084, function(){

    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", 8087);
});
```

However, I don't receive as expected. I receive the message in html with the message "Hello! This is an Axis2 Web Service!". It seems like the webservice is not executing.

Can someone help me why get this error?

Comment: You should correctly indent your code.